# CSS input:invalid incorrectly applied

Tags: css, html, validation

I have this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rkTCq/

The code is simply an input field of type number with pattern

```
pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?"
```

CSS adds a red border if input is invalid:

```
input:invalid { border:1px solid red; }
```

However, if I type 1.3 and then tab out the field, I get a red border, even though this is correct according to the pattern. What is wrong here?

**PS : This is in safari.**

Edit: OK, i added step="any" and this seems to fix it. Can you guys confirm?

http://jsfiddle.net/rkTCq/2/

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine for me. Not getting red border on 1.3

Comment: I'm getting the red border with Chrome.

Comment: Weird.  Works OK in FF but in Chrome I get a red border for 1.3 (which should be OK) but no red border for simply 1. (which should be invalid).  I see nothing wrong in the regex.

Comment: Weird, I am not getting the red border with any input in FF mobile. And @Adam 1 is valid input for that pattern.

Comment: Looks like Chrome is only accepting integer.  "1.0" is valid but "1.1", "1.3" etc are not

Comment: @Pietu1998 "1" is valid for the pattern.  "1." is not - if you have the decimal point then you must have at least one number after it.  or at least that is my reading of the pattern

Comment: Can you confirm if this works correctly, http://jsfiddle.net/rkTCq/2/ - i added step="any"

Comment: @Adam Oh, I thought the dot was not part of the input...

Comment: @Pietu1998 Yeah, I edited my other comment to have quote marks to make it clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've defined the input as `type=number`. As described in this article, floats must be explictly allowed using the `step` attribute in order to correctly validate.

https://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/

Add a step attribute: `step="any"` to your input:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" tabindex="2" step="any">
```

Additionally, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) `pattern` does not apply to the `number` type:

> This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text,
>   search, tel, url or email; otherwise it is ignored

Comment: OK in this case, do I even need the pattern? Is step supported by all browsers? I do not want to allow ,

Comment: I don't think `pattern` is used in this case. If you add `step="any"` any floating point number validates just fine, for example `1.2e-10`. As for browser support, it is supported by particular versions of all the major browsers - see the linked MDN page for details on which ones

Comment: One additional potential complication: not all langauges use a dot as a decimal seperator (in Sweden and Finland they use comma instead). I'm not sure how the "number" type behaves if your computer is using such a culture - I would have expected it to use the langauge from the page, not the client, but haven't actually tested.  Has anyone?

Comment: @Adam Very good point, from a quick Google around it appears that Chrome does not allow for a comma separator regardless of locale. Period ;)